# Sharding workload with distributed JMeter servers instead of mirroring

Tags: jmeter

The default behavior of JMeter definitely seems to just duplicate your test plan across servers.  So, if the test plan has 10 "threads", running it against X servers will yield 10x threads.

Is there any way to make this more intelligent?  For example, maybe I only want one copy of some HTTP thread running even though I have 5 servers to distribute a more intense load.

Another example...I want to ensure that my sampler uses unique IDs for each thread, but my service requires that the usernames be pre-provisioned so they can't be preprovisioned...I haven't been able to find a straightforward way to coordinate this (statelessly) across my distributed servers.

A "simple" implementation might be if JMeter had distributed testing aware variables built in so the client sent the server something like *ServerID* and *ServerCount* so that the test plan could use the numeric serverId as a prefix or mod by the server count.  Alternatively, JMeter could have an option to shard thread_num so that if you say 10,000 threads and have 10 servers, it will run 1,000 threads on each server with thread_num never being duplicated across the distributed test for a given sampler  (Example, skip thread_num if thread_num % serverCount != serverId).

Any thoughts on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I believe Jenkins will give you that flexibility. By design JMeter slaves are dumb nodes and they only know to replicate the script and execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to have distributed test-aware variable is to start each jmeter-server with different variable value:

```
bin/jmeter-server -Jvariable=valuehost1
```

And then in your test script just use:

```
${__P(variable)}
```